# Ошибка в opencv_core2410.dll после сборки проекта под VS 2019

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2019

Есть большой проект с распознаванием лиц который разрабатывался в Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2010, появилась задача мигрировать проект для дальнейшей разработки на Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2019. Миграция проекта прошла успешно, все основные функции и модули проекта работают, но есть одна проблема при попытке чтения CascadeClassifier из xml файла возникает ошибка: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x79C8A5A9 (opencv_core2410.dll) в sdkDemo.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00000001.

Вот код при выполнении которого происходит исключение:

```
void CsdkDemoDlg::initDetectors(CascadeClassifier &faceCascade)
{

    // Load the Face Detection cascade classifier xml file.
    try {  

        faceCascade.load("C:\\lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"); <<<<<<<-------Вот здесь вылетает ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ

    } catch (cv::Exception &e) {}
}
```

Библиотеки и инклуды все подключены как положено, проект компилируется и запускается без ошибок., при миграции проекта код программы не менялся, используется библиотека Open CV 2.4.1, при сборке на VS 2010 все работает без исключений...

Помогите плиз найти проблему, готов предоставлять всю необходимую дополнительную информацию. Спасибо.

Comment: Самое обыкновенное разыменование nullptr. Непонятно только что вы пытаетесь выяснить на форуме?

Comment: Пытаюсь выяснить как можно решить эту проблему, так как самостоятельно решить ее не получается! Большая просьба дать совет в какую сторону двигаться

Comment: просто не все знают, что ссылки могут быть nullptr. Да, я понимаю, что это звучит как конщунство, но если вызвать initDetectors и передать ей разыменованный nullptr, то все будет очень весело. Показывайте вызывающую сторону или смотрите в стек вызовов.